# reading innerText fails

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I'm trying to get value of TextBox1 the following way:

```
  document.getElementById("TextBox1").innerText
```

but for some reason it doesn't work, I tried it in Chrome and IE. when I do:

```
  document.getElementById("TextBox1").style.backgroundColor
```

I get the values, so for some reason it doesn't work only with innerText. is there an alternative way to get value of a textbox? thanks!

Comment: document.getElementById("TextBox1").value won't do the trick?

Comment: What about innerHtml?

Comment: Oh, is it input type=text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access its `value` property:

```
 document.getElementById("TextBox1").value
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the tag name but if it is input[type=text] so use .value property

Comment: probably answered too late